# Why can't we call Thread#sleep() directly inside a Lambda function?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8

The below code is giving me a compile time error:

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try { 
        sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
});
```

> **The method sleep(int) is undefined for the type A**  (where A is my class name).

Whereas, when I use an anonymous inner class, there is no compile time error:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
};
```

The below code also works fine:

```
Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("In lambda"));
```

How do things work inside a lambda expression body? Please help.

From many answers, I can see that the error can be resolved using `Thread.sleep(1000)` in my first approach. However, I'd really appreciate if someone could explain to me how scope and context work in a lambda expression.

Comment: What is the compiler error you are getting?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, The method sleep(int) is undefined for the type A, Here A is my class Name.

Comment: have you tried to import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

Comment: I mean, just reference static methods in a static way, and it would prevent a lot of issues like this. It's good that you're clarifying why it isn't working though.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` is a static method in the `Thread` class.

The reason you can call `sleep` directly without any qualifiers in an anonymous class is because you are actually in the context of a class that inherits from `Thread`. Therefore, `sleep` is accessible there.

But in the lambda case, you are not in a class that inherits from `Thread`. You are inside whatever class is surrounding that code. Therefore, `sleep` can't be called directly and you need to say `Thread.sleep`. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables) also supports this:

> Lambda expressions are lexically scoped. This means that they do not
>   inherit any names from a supertype or introduce a new level of
>   scoping. Declarations in a lambda expression are interpreted just as
>   they are in the enclosing environment.

Basically that is saying that inside the lambda, you are actually in the same scope as if you were outside of the lambda. If you can't access `sleep` outside the lambda, you can't on the inside either.

Also, note that the two ways of creating a thread that you have shown here is intrinsically different. In the lambda one, you are passing a `Runnable` to the `Thread` constructor, whereas in the anonymous class one, you are creating a `Thread` by creating an anonymous class of it directly.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables) says: _the lambda expression does not introduce a new level of scoping. Consequently, you can directly access fields, methods, and local variables of the enclosing scope._

Comment: You can still use `import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;`. But having to catch `InterruptedException` creates far more visual noise than a preceding `Thread.`. So, to create a new thread which just sleeps one second, I’d use `new Thread(() -> LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)))` instead.

Comment: @Holger as far as I understand, this is a bit dangerous, if this thread is calling unpack, somewhere else that you might not have control of, this `park` will effectively not park at all. just sayin...

Comment: To me the last part of your answer is the most relevant to OP's problem.

Comment: @Eugene that’s exactly the same scenario as someone calling `interrupt`. Whether you catch the `InterruptedException` and proceed silently or use a method that returns silently in the first place, makes no difference. Except that the latter is likely more efficient.

Comment: @Holger well catching the `InterruptedException` at least signals the fact that you got interrupted, in case of `park/unpark` - you simply will not know; but if you consider ignoring it and proceed silently, than this is OK, I guess

Comment: @Eugene I don’t see how `catch (InterruptedException e) {}`, as used half a dozen times on this Q&A tells you anything. All I said, is that I’d use `parkNanos` instead of `try { Thread.sleep(…); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}`, to make the lambda expression more concise. If you are planning to add a more sophisticated exception handling here, you surely don’t use a lambda expression. Not to speak of never using `Thread.sleep(…)` in production code anyway.

Comment: @Holger miscommunication really; I was taking in general, sorry, now you make sense, totally

Comment: Isn't a lambda holding an implicit reference to the enclosing class? For example in Android when declaring a lambda inside an Activity does it hold on to its parent instance implicitly? (that is the Activity itself)

Comment: Look at yyyy’s answer at the bottom there. That’s kind of what happens under the hood with lambdas @microwth

Answer (score 20):

In the first approach, you are passing a `Runnable` to the `Thread`, you need call `Thread.sleep`:

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
});
```

it is the short version of:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
};

Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
```

While in the second, you are overriding `thread.run` method directly, so it's ok to call `thread.sleep` in `thread.run`.

Comment: For me this is this answer explain better than the others. In the others I got lost about why talking about anonymous class vs lambda when the problem was exactly what you're saying.

Comment: Exactly this. Just because you don't explicitly _see_ the class type of the lambda doesn't mean it no longer exists. You're still inside another class.

Comment: +1, though it's important to note that the lambda can't refer to any fields/methods of `Runnable`, either; something like `Runnable runnable = () -> run();` won't compile, unlike `Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { public void run() { run(); } };`.

Answer (score 10):

This ends up being a misunderstanding of Scope.

When you are passing in a lambda to the thread, you are not creating a subclass of Thread, instead you are passing in the FunctionalInterface of [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and calling a constructor of Thread. When you attempt to call Sleep, the context of your scope is a combination of Runnable + your class (you can call default methods if the Runnable interface had them), not Thread.

Runnable does not have sleep() defined, but Thread does.

When you create an anonymous inner class, you are subclassing Thread, so sleep() is available for you to call, as the context of the Scope is a subclass of Thread.

Calling static methods, without the class name is discouraged for exactly this kind of misunderstanding. Using Thread.Sleep is both correct, and unambiguous in all circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

Your doubt originates on a misunderstanding about how the *scopes* of a lambda expression and an anonymous class are defined. Below, I will try to clarify this.

Lambda expressions DO NOT introduce a new level of scoping. This means that, inside it, you can only access the same things that you would be able to access in the immediately enclosing code block. See what the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables) say:

> Lambda expressions are lexically scoped. This means that they do not
> inherit any names from a supertype or introduce a new level of
> scoping. Declarations in a lambda expression are interpreted just as
> they are in the enclosing environment.

Anonymous classes work differently. They do introduce a new level of scoping. They behave much like a [*local class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) (a class that you declare inside a block of code), although they can't have constructors. See what the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing) say:

> Like local classes, anonymous classes can capture variables; they have the same access to local variables of the enclosing scope:
>
> - An anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
> - An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.
> - Like a nested class, a declaration of a type (such as a variable) in an anonymous class shadows any other declarations in the enclosing
>   scope that have the same name. See Shadowing for more information.

In this context, the anonymous class will act like a local class inside `Thread` and, thus, it will be able to access `sleep()` directly, since this method will be within its scope. However, in the lambda expression, `sleep()` won't be within its scope (you can't call `sleep()` on the enclosing environment), so that you must use `Thread.sleep()`. Note that this method is *static* and, therefore, doesn't require an instance of its class in order to be called.

Comment: *doubt --> question. These are not synonyms in English. (I see this commonly from non-native speakers).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! However, isn't every question based on a doubt? In the context above, I was referring to the doubt that originated the question I was trying to answer. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

Following code works:

```
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    });
```

This is because `sleep(int milliseconds)` is a method from `Thread` class while you are creating and passing a `Runnable` instance to `Thread` class constructor.

In the second method, You are creating an anonymous inner class instance of `Thread` class and thus have access to all `Thread` class methods.

Answer (score 4):

I like the answer that was provided and accepted, but in much simpler words, you can think that `this` has changed from a anonymous inner class to a lambda.

In case of a AIC, `this` refers to an instance of a class you are extending (in your example that being `Thread`), in case of `lambda expression`, `this` refers to an instance of the class that surrounds the lambda expression (whatever that class is in your example). And I bet in your class where you use the lambda expression, there is not such `sleep` defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void foo() {
    new Thread(() -> { sleep(1000); });
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void foo() {
    new Thread(this::lambda$0);
}
private void lambda$0() {
    sleep(1000);
}
```

so compiler will not lookup `sleep` in `Thread`

Answer (score -2):

Thread.sleep is static method ...

```
 Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    });
```

Comment: that is not the point. It is a method of Thread but the Lambda is being defined in the user class, just being used to create a Thread